# Finding largest number in c program

Tags: arrays, c

The brief is to input 10 salaries, compute commission, and overall take home, and print highest takehome. I am able to get the highest number, but for the number inputted, and not for the takehome (which I calculate). I wonder how I do this as I'm not storing the take home values I'm calculating? Is this my issue? Please see code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    int num[10];
    int i = 0;
    int largest;
    int com, totaltakehome, finalsalary;
         
    while(i < 10)
    {
        printf("Enter salesperson salary for week[%d]:", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
        com = num[i] / 100 * 7;
        printf("Commision is %d\n", com);
        totaltakehome = 300 + com;
        printf("Total takehome is %d\n", totaltakehome);
        printf("\n");
    }

    largest = num[0];
    i = 0;
    while(i < 10)
    {
        if(num[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = num[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("\nHighest salary is : %d\n", largest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first `while` loop will never terminate as you never increment `i` inside it. You should at least debug your code once before posting a question on SO

Comment: Are you aware of the difference of `i+1` (expression) and `i++` (increment)?

Comment: Hint: You don't need an array at all. Just make the calculations directly in the loop and check if the current takehome is greater than the largest takehome. If it is, save that.

Comment: In order to convince yourself (and if you don't use a debugger), output `i` somewhere.

Comment: I++ increments i by one meaning if i = 3 it is now 4 I+1 means that I = 3 but you are referring to 3+1

Comment: Anyway, welcome to SO, and a big whooping +1 for actually posting a working example of your problem. -- Sidenote: **Never** use `scanf()` on user input without checking the return value. Your `num[i]` might end up uninitialized if the user happens to enter something that isn't a decimal, with the subsequent `num[i] / 100 * 7` (erroneous as Ted pointed out above because integer divisions are always truncated towards zero) being *undefined behavior* as well.

Comment: `num[i] / 100` is integer division. Perhaps you want `num[i] * 7 / 100` to form a more generous commission.  IMO, the commission calculation should _round_ too, so `(num[i] * 7 + 50) / 100`.

Comment: " I am able to get the highest number, but for the number inputted, and not for the takehome (which I calculate)." --> What did you input?  What did you get, what did you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since none of the previously entered salaries are needed to calculate ...

- the largest commission
- the total takehome

... you can skip the `num[10]` array.

- You *do* need to increase `i` in the loop. `i+1` is an expression which does not change the value of `i`. I suggest using a `for` loop for this which keeps the declaration of `i`, the condition (`i < 10`) and the increment nicely in one place.
- You should check the return value from `scanf`. If you scan for *one* thing, it should return `1`, otherwise it failed.
- Save the largest commission in the loop.
- Initialize variables.
- Add to `totaltakehome`. You currently *assign* a new value to it in every loop.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int largest = 0;       // initialized (and assuming this can't be negative)
    int totaltakehome = 0; // initialized

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {  // loop with increment
        printf("Enter salesperson salary for week[%d]:", i + 1);

        int num;
        if(scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {   // check for success
            fprintf(stderr, "user error, aborting\n");
            return 1;
        }

        // an alternative commission forumla
        int com = num * 7 / 100; // perhaps a more fair commission

        printf("Commision is %d\n", com);

        // save this commission if it's the largest so far:
        if(com > largest) largest = com;

        // Add to `totaltakehome` - don't assign:
        totaltakehome += 300 + com;    // note: `+=`, not `=`

        printf("\n");
    }

    // print results after the loop:
    printf("Largest commision %d\n", largest);
    printf("Total takehome is %d\n", totaltakehome);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ted, I think your advice was great, and your example code. I've built on what you gave me and gone through it to make sure I have a clear understanding. I've since executed it and it is doing exactly as I would hope, so thank you again. I think most importantly from this I saw my mistakes with your explanation (as well as everyone else) and that's what I ultimately want. I may have more questions to further my understanding so I hope it's OK to repeat post here as I go through it in more detail. Thank you again.

Comment: @StephNolan You are very welcome and if you need some explanation regarding this particular Q&A, feel free to ask comment here.

Comment: Thank you very much. Still getting to grips with how SO works. I've since accepted those comments which were useful in guiding me get to the correct answer. I've gone through the code I initially put up line by line and made sure I'm aware of my mistakes. Similarly, I went through my new code and made sure I understood every action. I feel 100% confident in it now, and feel I learned a lot. Really appreciate the direction, only on week 2 of a course and it's daunting.

Comment: @StephNolan  Glad it helped! It's not the simplest of programming languages for sure - but it's really powerful and nice when you get the hang of it!

Answer (score 1):

We can use a basic for loop for the answer.

```
int old = arr[0];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > old) old = arr[i];
}

return old;
```

First we create a loop that runs ten times or we can also use

```
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
```

For an unknown list size. Forgive me for I am on mobile.

Then we check if the next number is bigger than our old biggest known if so set it to be the biggest. If so, we will set it to be our biggest. Then we finally return our value. (This is a function btw)

Comment: Instead of simply providing the code for a solution, you may also want to provide a short explanation in your answer why OP's code was wrong.

Comment: I am on a mobile device and accidentally pressed enter my bad

Comment: Try `int old = arr[0];for(i=1;i<10...`

Comment: I’ll try adding that since mine is a quick hack and oversight

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I'll give it another go tonight and hopefully be back with success. Really appreciate it and apologies for the mistakes, I'm very new and still making a lot of silly mistakes. Hoping to improve.