# I am trying to find the biggest number from a for loop

Tags: c

My code is about measuring the distance from different point then telling the biggest distance among them. I am finished with rest of the thing but I just cant find the biggest number among them. I tried using a different variable distance2 but it is creating more problem.
How can I find the biggest number and the point that biggest number has. I kept trying

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Function proto-type declarations */
void where_is_xy(float x, float y);
float compute_distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2);
float saveit, xmax, ymax, x2max, y2max, saveit1,prime;


/* Function definitions */
void where_is_xy(float x, float y) {
    if (x > 0 && y > 0)
    {
        printf("quadriant 1st\n");
    }
    else if (x < 0 && y < 0)
    {
        printf("quandriant 3rd\n");
    }
    else if (x > 0 && y < 0)
    {
        printf("quandriant 4th\n");
    }
    else if (x < 0 && y>0)
    {
        printf(" quandriant 2nd\n");
    }
    else if (x == 0 && (y > 0 || y < 0))
    {
        printf("Y axis\n");
    }
    else if (y == 0 && (x > 0 || x < 0))
    {
        printf("x axis\n");
    }
    }

float compute_distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    float calculation = sqrt((pow((x1 - x2), 2) + pow((y1 -
        y2), 2)));
    printf(" The between distance is %0.2f\n", calculation );
    return calculation; 
}

int main(void)
{
    /*float saveit;*/
    float x1, y1, x2, y2;
    printf("\nEnter (x, y): ");
    scanf_s("\n%f %f", &x2, &y2);
    where_is_xy(x2, y2);

    float distance1 = 0;
    
    for (int i =1; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        printf("\nEnter (x, y): ");
        scanf_s("\n%f %f", &x1, &y1);
        where_is_xy(x1, y1);
        
        float distance2 = compute_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        
if (distance2 > distance1)
{
    }
x2 = x1; y2 = y1;
//distance1 = distance2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding largest number in c program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70021589/finding-largest-number-in-c-program)

Comment: You should tell us what "problems" and "more problems" are. Also, What are you trying to do with `\n` in `scanf_s`? It is almost certainly isn't doing what you think it will.

Comment: OT: `where_is_xy()` will not report for x = 0.0, y = 0.0 because that is the missing "Origin"...

Answer (score 3):

1. You could create an array, then use a function to organize them from smallest to largest.
2. You could create two variables like it looks like you were talking about (`num1`, `num2`) then every time a new number pops up, you set `num2` equal to it, and run an if-statement to determine if it's larger than `num1`, if it's not then just move on to the next one and let `num2` get replaced, otherwise delete `num1` and move number to the `num1`.

Comment: yes your second one helped. Thank you. I haven't learnt about array so

Comment: Another approach is to traverse over the array recursively and find the maximum element.